# [stimulsoft]: one master with three separate details

Tags: master-detail, stimulsoft

I'm new in stimulsoft.I'm trying to build a report with three tables which I know I should use master details but I can't find a way. 
well, I have three tables.

1.Info(Date,name,type,x,y)

2.cost(Date,Item,amount)

3.Bill(Date,BillNo,PaymentNo,Cost)

column Date is the key.
I want to group the information of these tables by date 
and under each group I want to show the information of each table in Separate databands.in this way:

> ## 5 Sep 2016
>
> name1,type1,x1,y1
>
> name2,type2,x2,y2
>
> Item1,amount1
>
> Item2,amount2
>
> Item3,amount3
>
> BillNo1,PaymentNo1,Cost1
>
> ## 4 Sep 2016
>
> name3,type3,x3,y3
>
> Item4,amount4
>
> Item5,amount5
>
> BillNo2,PaymentNo2,Cost2
>
> BillNo3,PaymentNo3,Cost3

- there are multiple rows with equal date in tables.
- I try many ways but it shows all cost and bill information per rows of info!!

Is there any way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group Header` (or `Group Footer`) within a `DataBand`.
Remember set the condition for your `Group Header` to your column Date like this:

```
{YourDataSource.Date}
```

By this, the Date field apear only once in the group.